# Discord.py on_member_join wont print

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(member)

    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="☾│Unregister Of Hyperion")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

This is my code, it should print the users nick when it joins, but it doesn't. The bot gives the role but it doesnt print. The same code works on my other bot. I have no idea why it doesnt work in this.

Comment: Idk it works perfectly fine for me. Did you check if it prints anything in general? Maybe try to just print out a random string to check if the function works and tell us the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are similar to permissions, you have to define Intents to get channels, members and some events etc. You have to define it before defining the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intent().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(member)
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="☾│Unregister Of Hyperion")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).