# discord bot Welcome message dont work .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```py
class Welcome (commands.Cog, name="join"):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member: discord.Member):
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Server Tag')
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(801949269165998080)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f'Hi {member.mention}, Welcome to the server', color=0x0bf9f9)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

When a member join on to the server, the bot does not respond with a message. What could be the problem`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on\_member\_join and on\_member\_leave not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62123044/discord-py-on-member-join-and-on-member-leave-not-working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py: on_member_join suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410314/discord-py-on-member-join-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on_member_join wont print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536565/discord-py-on-member-join-wont-print)

Comment: You could at least google your question, there's a ton of similar questions like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be you don't have [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) enabled, you can enable intents on the bot, based on what you need [here.](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

You do need to do a bit of coding to enable intents but I find it easy.

[image: The two toggled switches are intents.]

[image: This is how easy it could be.]

This is what I needed to code, in order for my intents to work. ^^^